# magento Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Generic' not found in Group.php on line 36

Tags: magento

1. I have all the additional magento  folders deleted on my server.
2. I have only one functioning magento shop
3. This is a good thing
4. I have downloaded from the one magento folder a backup via ftp to my hard drive.
5. Frontend works well  but I can't login backend which I am getting the following error message:

`Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Generic' not found in / var/www/web10/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Acl/Role/Group.php on line 36`

Also, I had remove  `var/cache` and  `var/session` contents but no success, still getting the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an incomplete download, or a corrupt Magento system.  The `Group.php` file referenced above contains a single Magento class definition, with no methods.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Acl/Role/Group.php
class Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Group extends Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Generic
{

}
```

PHP is saying it can't find the class `Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Generic` (which is the parent class of `Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Group`).  In a normal system, Magento's autoloader would find this class in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Acl/Role/Generic.php
```

However, in your system it's not finding this file.  The possible reasons for this are myriad, but my guess is the file doesn't exist.  Grab that file from your original system, or a from a fresh archive of Magento, and this specific problem will go away.

Comment: Hi Alan,


and Merry Christmas from Germany.

Thank you for your quick and detailed response.

In fact, the Generic.php was present but there was nothing in it.


I find that very strange!
Can something like this happen during a failed Dowload via a FTP client?

again thank you so much

Sincerely,


Karl Dennis Matthaei

Comment: You will quite often find these empty classes. Basically NOP functions that serve as placeholders. Just pulled `Generic.php` up and it's a placeholder as well: `class Mage_Admin_Model_Acl_Role_Generic extends Zend_Acl_Role { }`